# Google Sheets - Carrying over conditional formatting to a referenced cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have the below google sheet, in which cells in column C are conditionally formatted based on values in column G.  I have the conditional formatting working correctly, however when I reference the cells in column C elsewhere (in this example column A,) the conditional formatting does not carry over just the cell value.  Is there any way to get the conditional formatting to show in the referenced cells in A?

Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aHnZVDPzI6CFj-b_nZOOPdDpXf1zrP8ONetHIM3zxUY/edit#gid=0

Edit: To be more clear, the sheet below is meant as an example, the actual sheet has much more complex functionality and the values in column A will change.  What I am trying to accomplish is to just have the conditional formatting found in whatever cell column A is referencing to carry over.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'range' on the first conditional format rule from C2 to A2:C2.

Likewise on the other one, from C3 to A3:C3.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear (edited my post.)  I was trying to give a simple example since the actual sheet is much more complex, but the values in column A are formulated and will change based on conditions.  So what I'm trying to accomplish is to have whatever values appear in column A match those in column C's conditional formatting i.e. the strikethrough

Comment: I'm not quite following. If the format of A needs to follow C, and C is based on G, then would A not also follow G. Looking at your example sheet, what specifically do you need it to look like? Can you copy rows 2 and 3 to say 12 and 13 and modify the copy to show what you need?